# Google maps javascripts api with more than 100000 markes

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-maps-api-3

I have a google maps app in django a try to draw a map with near 200.000 markers, the time to load is around 45 seconds, I want to less it. I use MarkerClusterer for agregattion this markers, but the process spend more time es create the markers.

In a static .js, I have:

```
function addMarkers() { 
  add_marker(features)
   ... (others 200.000 lines)...
}(+- 40 MB)
```

It is posible compress it with (django-webpacker)?

And in the html file:

```
function add_marker(array){
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position:  new google.maps.LatLng(lt,lg),
             map: map,
            (with others features)
         });
             gmarkers.push(marker);

             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
                 window.open(...);
             });

             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function(){
                 this.info.open(map, this);
             });
   }

Clusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers, options);
```

Comment: I'm no doctor, but 45s for 200k markers sounds alright.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450927/google-maps-v3-rendering-over-1-million-markers-in-a-reasonable-time/30364282

Comment: @devlincarnate It is in streetmap, I want in google maps

Comment: @devlincarnate It is OpenstreetMap

Comment: The approach taken in the solution applies to Google Maps.  You won't be able to copy / paste the code, but you can use the same approach.

Comment: take a step back, and think about it: you have a 40MB JavaScript file; that has to be downloaded, then parsed and executed. I would have expected that it would take more than 45s to execute 40MB of JS.

Comment: @devlincarnateMy requirements at different of your example, and I can't use it. I must try with other method.

Comment: I agree with Thomas.  Probably a better approach is to put your data on a database.  This means you can filter on server side; the server then only sends a limited number of markers, depending on zoom level and boundaries.  (I don't know how to do this in python & django)